# How does RedHat determine the number of cores

Tags: linux, configuration, centos, redhat, multicore

First let me clarify what I am *not* asking -- I already know how to determine the number of cores that linux thinks it has, by querying items in /sys/devices/system/cpu such as ./possible and ./present, and by using lstopo, dmidecode, etc.

What I want to know is, how does the kernel arrive at the particular numbers one sees there in sys/devices/system/cpu/present ?

The motivation for this is that I have in my lab two identical processor boards, both with quad core i7-2715QE processors on them. One board, for simplicity's sake call this the 'good' board, reports as four cores (as expected) with hyperthreading (HT) on, for a total of 8 cpus. The *other* board reports only two cores, again with HT on, for a total of just 4 cpus.

Something upstream of sys/devices/system/cpu must be making the determination that two of the cores are not to be used. The 'good' board lists 0-7 in sys/.../possible and sys/.../present, whereas the 'bad' board shows 0-3, and yet they have the identical i7-2715QE on them.

I checked the BIOS/UEFI screens for any differences and didn't find anything there. There are no physical switches/jumpers on the board, that I can find. Could this have been something compiled into the kernel? Are the bootline options to Grub that I should look at?  Both boards are running RedHat 6. The good board is at 6.3, the other one at 6.6, but these are similar enough to not innately make a difference in this regard. I.e., I don't think the *version itself* matters as much as the possibility that they're just build differently.

**update**

It's definitely something to do with the OS image or possibly the grub settings, b/c when booted from an external live image, the bad board shows the expected cpu0..cpu7 in sysfs. Something about what's in the on-board flash must be disabling two of the four cores.

Comment: Hey, you closer types -- how about give it 10 minutes for someone to find a place to migrate it to?

Comment: Can you try booting a live cd from another distro, just to get a second opinion? Some of our dual-core xeons would occasionally show just one core, regardless of distro, and we figured it was a hardware problem.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick yes, was going to try that yesterday but ran out of time. So, booted from a usb stick, bad board shows the expected 8 cpu entries in sysfs. Which leads to, how is it that the OS flashed on the bad board fails to see cores 2 and 3 ..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the acpi option on the boot line is the culprit. For reasons not yet determined, specifying acpi=off was causing the kernel to misinterpret the cpu topology, and what should have been 4 cores with hyperthreading capability was taken to mean 4 cpus as 2 cores using hyperthreading.

Setting acpi=ht seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, answered my own, b/c lost count of the times that a search turns up one lonely question with no answers